# 'no such table' error when loading external databese

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I am trying to make a application that will take an SQLite database I already made and be able to read/write that database.I followed from [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) site.when I try to run my application and insert or read data from database.
LogCat keeps telling me that there is no table named User,which is a table in the database that I know I created and put into my assets folder in the project

```
11-28 08:15:06.469: E/SQLiteLog(1945): (1) no such table: User
```

I created an Adapter which also contains an SQLiteHelper nested class.
can any one help me with this error?how can I handle it?
**Edit2**

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

private final String TAG = "DatabaseAdapter";
private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;

public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
    openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, "DietDatabase.db",
            null, 1);
}
public DatabaseAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
{
    try 
    {
        openHelper.createDataBase();
    } 
    catch (IOException mIOException) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
        throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
    }
    return this;
}

public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    try 
    {
        openHelper.openDataBase();
        openHelper.close();
        mDb = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    } 
    catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
    return this;
}

 public void close() 
    {
     openHelper.close();
    }


// for User table ==================================================

public static final String TABLE_USER = "User";
public static final String TABLE_USER_ID = "_id";
public static final String TABLE_USER_HEIGHT = "_height";
public static final String TABLE_USER_WEIGHT = "_weight";
public static final String TABLE_USER_AGE = "_age";
public static final String TABLE_USER_GENDER = "_gender";
public static final String TABLE_USER_PA = "_pa";
public static final String TABLE_USER_BMIVALUE = "_bmivalue";
public static final String TABLE_USER_BMIINTERPRETATION = "_bmiInterpretation";
public static final String TABLE_USER_IDEALWEIGHT = "_idealweight";
public static final String TABLE_USER_DAILYCALORIES = "_dailycalories";

public int getuserid(){
int id;
SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;
 myDataBase = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cur = myDataBase.query(TABLE_USER, 
        null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
id=cur.getInt(0);
    cur.close();

return id;}

// insert into user table======================================================
public Long insertUser(User user) {
SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;
Long id = -1L;
try {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TABLE_USER_HEIGHT, user.getHeight());
    values.put(TABLE_USER_WEIGHT, user.getWeight());
    values.put(TABLE_USER_AGE, user.getAge());
    values.put(TABLE_USER_GENDER, user.getGender());
    values.put(TABLE_USER_PA, user.getPa());
    values.put(TABLE_USER_BMIVALUE, user.getBmivalue());
    values.put(TABLE_USER_BMIINTERPRETATION,
            user.getBmiInterpretation());
    values.put(TABLE_USER_IDEALWEIGHT, user.getIdealweight());
    values.put(TABLE_USER_DAILYCALORIES, user.getDailycalories());

    myDataBase = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    id = myDataBase.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (myDataBase != null && myDataBase.isOpen())
        myDataBase.close();
}
return id;
}

//databaseOpenHelper=========================================================

static class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static String TAG1 = "DatabaseOpenHelper";

        public static File DB_PATH ;

        private static String DB_NAME = "DietDatabase.db";

        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

        private final Context myContext;



        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            DB_PATH=context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
            this.myContext = context;
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (dbExist) {

            } else {

                this.getReadableDatabase();
                this.close();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();
                    Log.e(TAG1, "createDatabase database created");


                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }

        }
        private boolean checkDataBase() {

             File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
                //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
                return dbFile.exists();
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            // Open local db as the input stream

            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db

            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            // Open the empty db as the output stream

            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

            // Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        }
        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

            if (myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }
   }
```

where I use database

```
DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(BmiCalculaterPage.this);
            dbAdapter.createDatabase();      
            dbAdapter.open();
            dbAdapter.insertUser(user);
            int x=dbAdapter.getuserid();
            dbAdapter.close();
```

when I traced it I found application stoped when trying to return the value of x but I cant find why this accrue?

Comment: where you create user table ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana I worked with navicat GUI for creating tables and also inserting static data then export database and copy it to asset folder.
also creat class model for work easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply writing

```
super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
```

in `DatabaseOpenHelper`'s constructor.

Here istead of DB_NAME, you need to give the path + DB_NAME like below,

```
super(context, EXTERNAL_PATH + "\" + DB_NAME, null, 1);
```

Now it will point to the db you have in your external storage. Previously the code was searching DB in the local path of application.

Comment: I Edit it another time.

Comment: @mimi, can you show me the code, that how are you calling `DatabaseOpenHelper` class ?

Comment: look at `public DatabaseAdapter createDatabase()` part please. u can see `openHelper.createDataBase();` called

Comment: I recently start working with database so I have lots of problem with it.

Comment: @mimi, right, but before that line's code get execute, the following line's code will execute first `openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, "DietDatabase.db",
            null, 1);` which actually call the constructor where there is a mistake of path like i described in the answer

Comment: Please come to this [Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64922/room-for-erick-and-kedarnath)